# Overlay data on image file aligning with grid lines

Tags: image, matlab, alignment, overlay, axis

My aim is to plot an image file in MATLAB and aligning it as closely to the ticks from the image then overlay data points. The image file was screen captured from a pdf report (link below). The data is loglog. The image file axis has lower and upper bounds of.

```
xstart 1e-2 to xend 1e5 % frequency and 
ystart 1e-7 yo yend 1e-1 % amplitude
```

I would like to plot the following data values on top of the image

```
frequency = [1 3 10 30 100 300 1000 3000 10000]; 
amplitude = [7e-3 8e-4 1.3e-4 4e-5 2e-5 1.8e-5 1.7e-5 1.65e-5 1.6e-5];
```

(Or any vector values I get from computation for example vector "B" as a function of frequency vector "f")

The issue I have is the .pdf image has grid lines.  As a consequence misaligning data points and making it look unaesthetic with axis labels.Thanks

[image file](http://tinypic.com/r/14sod5l/8)

I think it's best to align the log ticks as closely as possible with the image file. Below is my code. I haven't worked out how to align the tick axis with the image exactly yet (when zoomed in), (i'm sure you can do this manually, but if there is an elegant image process mathematical method would be nice).

```
imgInputlf = imread('RMIT_Input_Noise_Lowf.png');
[nrows,ncols,dim]=size(imgInputlf);
figure(1)
f = logspace(-2,5,ncols);
amp=logspace(-7,-1,nrows);
xrng=[min(f) max(f)];yrng=[min(amp) max(amp)];
imagesc(xrng,yrng,imgInputlf)
ax1=gca;
set(ax1,'YTickLabel', [], 'XTickLabel', []) % remove pixel ticklabels
set(findobj(gcf, 'type','axes'), 'Visible','off')

Freq = [1 3 10 30 100 300 1000 3000 10000]; % data
Amp = [7e-3 8e-4 1.3e-4 4e-5  2e-5  1.8e-5 1.7e-5  1.65e-5  1.6e-5]; %data

ax2 = axes('Position',get(ax1,'Position'),'Color','none','YScale', 'log','XScale','log');    %color=none to make the image visible
ylim(yrng)
xlim(xrng)
hold on
loglog(Freq,Amp,'k','LineWidth',4) % plot data  end
```

Comment: So what do you want to do- remove the grid lines/ticks from the image, or remove the axis labels MATLAB adds when you plot the values?

Comment: Hi, I guess which ever looks more aesthetically more pleasing. Removing matlab ticks and aligning them with the image. Obviously necessary for the data points to coincide.